# If $\alpha$ is transcendental, why is the evaluation homomorphism $k[t] \to k(\alpha)$ not onto? What does a general element in $k(\alpha)$ look like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$.

Isn't every element in $k(\alpha)$ a polynomial in $\alpha$ over $k$?

If so, then I don't see why the evaluation homomorphism is not onto.

If every element of $k(\alpha)$ is a not a polynomial in $\alpha$ over $k$, then I must ask: What does a general element look like?

Comment: Think of the name of $k(\alpha)$: "rational expressions in $\alpha$"...

Comment: @paulgarrett My guess now would be that $1/\alpha$ has no preimage in $k[t]$?

Comment: Exactly... $k[\alpha]$ is an isomorphic image of $k[x]$, more-or-less by definition, but/and certainly $k(x)$ is bigger than $k[x]$, namely, its fraction field, so $k(\alpha)$ has to be isomorphic to that considerably larger thing... more-or-less by the definition of "transcendental".

Comment: Right.  The more interesting (to me) result is that if $\alpha$ is algebraic, then the evaluation homomorphism to the fraction field *is* surjective.

Comment: @RobertShore In which case, we mod out $k[t]$ by the ideal generated by the minimal polynomial, say $p(t)$, to get $k[t]/(p(t)) \cong k(\alpha)$?

Comment: Yes.  Proving that's an isomorphism is non-trivial, but it's not hard.